# How to index each tcolorbox box by a number/total fraction?

Tags: tcolorbox

To create a course summary, I created a `tcolorbox` that I call for each new page. There is therefore only 1 box per summary page.

This summary is indexed by `1/2` (first page on a total of 2) `2/2` (second page on a total of 2), etc.

- To number each page, I used `auto counter` which normally counts the number of boxes. But as here, there are as many boxes as there are pages, it comes back in practice to the same.
- To get the total number of pages, I created a label `label={number-of-pages}`.

It compiles perfectly but I get a warning.

> LaTeX Warning: Label `nombre-de-page' multiply defined.

#### Is it possible to number each page in the same way without creating a warning?

- `1/2` and `2/2` for 2 pages;
- `1/3` then `2/3` and `3/3` for 3 pages;
- Or `1/4`; `2/4`; `3/4` and `4/4` for 4 pages;
- etc

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boite resumé

\def\couleurresume{red}%

% style du titre « résumé du cours »
\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
    boxed title style={
        colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
        colback=\couleurresume!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
}

% style des soustitres des résumés
\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
    subtitle style={%
    colback=\couleurresume!7,%
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{\couleurresume!63!black}}}}
}

% style du titre-boxed des encadrés
\tcbset{titrecadre/.style={%
    minipage boxed title*=-.5\linewidth,
    boxed title style={
        boxrule=.8pt,boxsep=0pt,toptitle=0pt,
        colframe=\couleurresume!55,colback=white},
    halign title=left}
}

% boite créant la boite résumé
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{resume}[2][]{%
    label={nombre-de-page},
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    before upper={
        \textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1} \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\pageref{nombre-de-page}}},
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=\couleurresume!63!black,%
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    titreresume,soustitre,title={\normalsize Résumé}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}

\newpage

\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

The numbering is highlighted in yellow.

[image: première boite]

[image: deuxième boite]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boite resumé

\def\couleurresume{red}%

% style du titre « résumé du cours »
\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
    boxed title style={
        colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
        colback=\couleurresume!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
}

% style des soustitres des résumés
\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
    subtitle style={%
    colback=\couleurresume!7,%
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{\couleurresume!63!black}}}}
}

% style du titre-boxed des encadrés
\tcbset{titrecadre/.style={%
    minipage boxed title*=-.5\linewidth,
    boxed title style={
        boxrule=.8pt,boxsep=0pt,toptitle=0pt,
        colframe=\couleurresume!55,colback=white},
    halign title=left}
}

% boite créant la boite résumé
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{resume}[2][]{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    before upper={
        \textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1} \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\pageref{nombre-de-page}}},
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=\couleurresume!63!black,%
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    titreresume,soustitre,title={\normalsize Résumé}
}


\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-page}{{}{\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}

\newpage

\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is better (this way the "one page = one box" condition can be lifted):

```
\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
%  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-page}{{}{\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}}}%
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-page}{{}{\the\value{\tcbcounter}}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

It is very counter-intuitive that `tcolorbox` provides `\thetcbcounter` but stores the counter name in `\tcbcounter` so that one can not use `\the\value{tcbcounter}` as there is no LaTeX "tcbcounter" counter ! And I tried with `\thetcbcounter` above it does not work.

---

Ah even better now that I did `\show\tcbcounter`.

```
\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
%  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-page}{{}{\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}}}%
%  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-page}{{}{\the\value{\tcbcounter}}}}%
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-page}{{}{\thetcb@cnt@resume}}}%
}
\makeatother
```

This way you know how to get independent series of boxes and have a total number of them for each type, which you can use in `a/<total>` style, even using some formatting and not only arabic numerals.

---

---

Proof of concept of above explanations, but using `\ref` not `\pageref` for clarity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boite resumé

\def\couleurresume{red}%

% style du titre « résumé du cours »
\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
    boxed title style={
        colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
        colback=\couleurresume!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
}

% style des soustitres des résumés
\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
    subtitle style={%
    colback=\couleurresume!7,%
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{\couleurresume!63!black}}}}
}

% style du titre-boxed des encadrés
\tcbset{titrecadre/.style={%
    minipage boxed title*=-.5\linewidth,
    boxed title style={
        boxrule=.8pt,boxsep=0pt,toptitle=0pt,
        colframe=\couleurresume!55,colback=white},
    halign title=left}
}

% boite créant la boite résumé
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{resume}[2][]{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    before upper={
        \textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1} \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=\couleurresume!63!black,%
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    titreresume,soustitre,title={\normalsize Résumé}
}


\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}

\newpage

\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

%\show\tcbcounter
\end{document}
```

You can thus define independent series of numbered boxes and access for each series its total number of boxes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which deserves my vote. Is it possible to make sure that this counter is integrated into the definition of the box because I have created a personal package in which I place its definition and I would not want to have to write the code between makeatletter and makeatother every time I call this box?

Comment: @AndréC the code between `\makeatletter/makeatother` can be located in your package. Just make sure to issue `\RequirePackage{atveryend}` within it.

Comment: The technique can be applied to any kind of LaTeX counter serving to index "typeset entities". Attention for number of page to use the `\the\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax` because last  shipout output routine stepped the page counter. But for all other counters, use the last value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have at most one box per page, then you can simply rename `{nombre-de-page}` to `{nombre-de-page-\thepage}`. With this way, you'll be labeling the box uniquely. For the example you provided only changes happen in lines `40` and `47`. So we have

```
...
    label={nombre-de-page-\thepage},
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
...
    \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\pageref{nombre-de-page-\thepage}}},
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
...
```

Here is the log for the example you provided
[image]

and the log with `-\thepage` added
[image]

Ideally you'd just want to CTRL + F and replace all `{nombre-de-page}` to `{nombre-de-page-\thepage}` as I suggested, just in case if you're calling that label elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work as desired since it numbers `1/1` then `2/2` and not `1/2` then `2/2`.

Comment: @AndréC Apologies if I misunderstood your question but renaming the label only affects the label. So unless you're resetting the counter `page` later on, the page number is uniquely associated with each box. If this is the case, you can define a new counter and associate that with each box to prevent having duplicate labels. I'll edit in what I described

Comment: I do not dispute your reasoning, which seems correct, but in practice the result produced by this modification does not correspond to the one expected.