# How to have two optional parameters in a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I wrote a red course summary box. This box contains the code given in the [following answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470931/138900). It uses `\NewTColorBox` and `xparse` *(which I don't understand much about)*.

I would like to be able to make this color a parameter so that I can generate summaries of several colors.

This box already has an optional parameter: the school year.

- How to add a second optional parameter: color?
- Is it possible to make sure that the two optional parameters each have a default value in order to be able to give:

  - either both paramater?
  - either one of them?
  - or none?

[image: boîte page 1]

[image: boîte page 2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}
  }{%
    \ifnum\month<9%
    \sfrac{\the\numexpr\year-1}{\the\year}%
    \else
    \sfrac{\the\year}{\the\numexpr\year+1}%
    \fi
  }%
}

%\month=7
%\day=31

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boîte resumé

\def\couleurresume{red}%

%% style du titre « résumé du cours »
%\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
%    boxed title style={
%        colframe=#2!50,%
%        colback=#2!10,%
%        coltext=blue,%
%    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
%}
%
%% style des soustitres des résumés
%\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
%    subtitle style={%
%    colback=#2!7,%
%    colframe=#2!50,%
%    boxsep=1mm,
%    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}}}
%}

% boîte créant la boîte résumé
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+o+O{red}+m}{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    IfValueTF={#1}{%
      before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#3}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    }{%
      before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#3}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    },
    colframe=#2!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=#2!63!black,%
    leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,
    toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
    left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
%    titreresume,
    boxed title style={
        colframe=#2!50,%
        colback=#2!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt},
%    soustitre,
    subtitle style={%
    colback=#2!7,%
    colframe=#2!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}},
    title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{resume}[2017]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}

\newpage

\begin{resume}[2018,blue]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

%\show\tcbcounter
\end{document}
```

Comment: The options of `tcolorbox` macros etc. are meant to set the values for the local `tcolorbox` instance, but not to change the global settings -- that's what `\tcbset` is defined for. If you want a default color blue for the box settings, use it as the setting in the options when you define your box.

Comment: Okay, what about changing the color of the box with an optional parameter?

Comment: Which colour? The colour of the frame, of the background, the background colour of title or the font colour?

Comment: the color of the boxes which is given here by parameter #2

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is it possible to make sure that the two optional parameters each have a default value in order to be able to give either both; either one of them, or none?

Comment: Having two optional arguments in a row is bad design, actually, i.e. `\foo[A][B]{...}` is difficult to maintain. If you omit one of them, and say `\foo[B]{...}` how should TeX know whether you have dropped the first or the second optional argument? As long as you give both of them or omit both of them (assuming they have default values), there is no problem, but omitting just one is causing troubles. As for `xparse`, the `o` optional argument can't have a default value, but you can query whether it is given or not, which would simplify the question which opt. argument has been omitted...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88691/discussion-between-andrec-and-christian-hupfer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slight variation of the OP's self answer, shifting the 2nd optional argument to the end of the argument list, i.e. it will become the 3rd. argument and transforming the `o` - type of the first argument to `O`.

A syntax of `\foo[A][B]{...}` is bad design and difficult to handle by `TeX/LaTeX`, since it cannot decide what

`\foo[A]{}`

is supposed to be. Is `A` the first optional or the second optional argument? This is unclear.

The `o` - type specifier from `xparse` gives a way to decide whether the 1st or the 2nd opt. argument is omitted, but alas, it does not allow for default arguments.

`\foo[A]{...}[B]` however is clearly recognizable and `TeX` can distinguish between `#1` (being `A` here) and `#3` (being `B`), so \foo[A]{...}`and`\foo{...}[B]` is well-defined

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+O{\the\year}}{%
  \ifnum#1=\the\year%
  \ifnum\month<9%
  \sfrac{\the\numexpr#1-1}{#1}%     #1=2018 --> 2017/2018
  \else
  \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}%      #1=2018 --> 2018/2019
  \fi
  \else
  \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}%      
  \fi
}


% For checking reasons only...
%\year=2017
%\month=6

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boîte resumé

\def\couleurresume{red}%

%% style du titre « résumé du cours »
%\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
%    boxed title style={
%        colframe=#2!50,%
%        colback=#2!10,%
%        coltext=blue,%
%    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
%}
%
%% style des soustitres des résumés
%\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
%    subtitle style={%
%    colback=#2!7,%
%    colframe=#2!50,%
%    boxsep=1mm,
%    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}}}
%}

% boîte créant la boîte résumé
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+O{\the\year}+m+O{red}}{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
%    IfValueTF={#1}{%
    before upper={\textcolor{#3!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    % }{%
    %   before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    % },
    colframe=#3!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=#3!63!black,%
    leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,
    toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
    left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
%    titreresume,
    boxed title style={
        colframe=#3!50,%
        colback=#3!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt},
%    soustitre,
    subtitle style={%
    colback=#3!7,%
    colframe=#3!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#3!63!black}}},
    title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% No optional arguments -> defaults to current year and red
\begin{resume}{chapitre 1}
  \tcbsubtitle{Définition}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{resume}


% both optional arguments -> 2016/2017 and blue
\begin{resume}[2016]{chapitre 1}[blue]
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}


\newpage

% Only the first optional argument -> 2020 and red
\begin{resume}[2020]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

% Only the second optional argument  -> current year and green
\begin{resume}{chapitre 1}[green]

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}




%\show\tcbcounter
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do as in your previous answer: if the year is not given, the current school year is considered as given?

Comment: @AndréC: I'll try

Comment: @AndréC: See the update please

Comment: There is a miscalculation: 2018 must give the school year 2018/2019 and not 2017/2018.

Comment: @AndréC: No, that's not a miscalculation.  If month = 1 and you specify 2018, shouldn't the box 'think', it's 2017/2018? The older method was the better one, but you insist on the default values, screwing up the logic, in my point of view

Comment: As for me, I call 2018, the 2018/2019 school year since it is in 2018 that the school year begins.

Comment: @AndréC: I will change tomorrow. I have no time right now...

Comment: @AndréC probably school year is location-dependent. I am teaching a course *now* (January 2019) which is in school year 2018-19 here --- I am sure! (school year run from september to august here). Now, if you want the school year *starting this year*, that's a different thing. So you are both right, methink.

Comment: @Rmano: Of course the school year is location dependent. I used the logic, that 2018 refers back to 2017/2018 if the month <8 and to 2018/2019.... the idea with two default value optional arguments isn't the best, in my point of view

Comment: Your new way of calculating the school year is remarkable for its simplicity and finesse. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

I just found, just put each optional argument in square brackets.

```
\begin{resume}[2018][blue]{chapitre 1}
```

---

I have not yet managed to make sure that I can call this box by indicating only the color *(without giving the school year)*.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}
  }{%
    \ifnum\month<9%
    \sfrac{\the\numexpr\year-1}{\the\year}%
    \else
    \sfrac{\the\year}{\the\numexpr\year+1}%
    \fi
  }%
}

%\month=7
%\day=31

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boîte resumé

\def\couleurresume{red}%

%% style du titre « résumé du cours »
%\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
%    boxed title style={
%        colframe=#2!50,%
%        colback=#2!10,%
%        coltext=blue,%
%    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
%}
%
%% style des soustitres des résumés
%\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
%    subtitle style={%
%    colback=#2!7,%
%    colframe=#2!50,%
%    boxsep=1mm,
%    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}}}
%}

% boîte créant la boîte résumé
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+o+O{red}+m}{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    IfValueTF={#1}{%
      before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#3}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    }{%
      before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#3}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    },
    colframe=#2!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=#2!63!black,%
    leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,
    toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
    left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
%    titreresume,
    boxed title style={
        colframe=#2!50,%
        colback=#2!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt},
%    soustitre,
    subtitle style={%
    colback=#2!7,%
    colframe=#2!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}},
    title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{resume}[2017]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}

\newpage

\begin{resume}[2018][blue]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

%\show\tcbcounter
\end{document}
```

[image: boite rouge par défaut]

[image: boîte bleu]

Answer (score 2):

What about using different delimiters for the two optional parameters? Like this, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{D(){red}O{2018}+m}{%
    Color: #1; Year: #2; mandatory: #3\par
}
\begin{document}
\Test{only mandatory}
\Test(blue){with color}
\Test[2020]{with year}
\Test(green)[1999]{with everything}
\end{document}
```

which works and, in my opinion, is even easier to remember.

[image]

You can combine it with [Christian Hupfer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471554/38080) to have the current school year (changing the `O` here to a `o`).

You can also add a third optional argument with, for example, angle brackets that will be a comma separated string to add to the `tcolorbox` options.

Applied to your nsMWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+O{\the\year}}{%
  \ifnum\month<9%
  \sfrac{\the\numexpr#1-1}{#1}%     #1=2018 --> 2017/2018
  \else
  \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}%      #1=2018 --> 2018/2019
  \fi
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{D<>{}D(){red}O{\the\year}+m}{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#3] \hfill{#4}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    colframe=#2!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=#2!63!black,%
    leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,
    toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
    left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
%    titreresume,
    boxed title style={
        colframe=#2!50,%
        colback=#2!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt},
%    soustitre,
    subtitle style={%
    colback=#2!7,%
    colframe=#2!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}},
    title={\normalsize Résumé}, 
    #1
}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

% No optional arguments -> defaults to current year and red
\begin{resume}{chapitre 1}
  \tcbsubtitle{Définition}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{resume}


% both optional arguments -> 2021 and blue
\begin{resume}(blue)[2021]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}


\newpage

% Only the first optional argument -> 2020 and red
\begin{resume}[2020]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

% Only the second optional argument  -> current year and green
\begin{resume}(green){chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

%  New optional argument - add whatever to the options to the tcolorbox 
\begin{resume}<colback=red, toprule=1cm>(green){chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}



%\show\tcbcounter
\end{document}
```

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

Comment: +1 Your idea is interesting. Can you adapt it to my summary box?

Comment: @AndréC, done --- by the way, sorry for the color assassination of the last box...

Comment: It's really interesting, I really like your idea that made me understand the role of optional D-type arguments `D <char1> <char2> {default}`. And I also like Christian's version which places the second optional argument after the mandatory one. Choosing one of the two answers is a Cornelian dilemma.

Comment: Can you change the calculation of the school year so that `[2020]` gives `2020/2021` and not `2019/2020`?  Indeed, I refer to the school years according to their first calendar year.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the resume definition so it includes an argument that the OP named `\couleurresume` the I used `\def\couleurrsume{red}` and `\def\couleurresume{blue}` when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}
  }{%
    \ifnum\month<9%
    \sfrac{\the\numexpr\year-1}{\the\year}%
    \else
    \sfrac{\the\year}{\the\numexpr\year+1}%
    \fi
  }%
}

%\month=7
%\day=31

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% boîte resumé


%% style du titre « résumé du cours »
%\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
%    boxed title style={
%        colframe=#2!50,%
%        colback=#2!10,%
%        coltext=blue,%
%    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
%}
%
%% style des soustitres des résumés
%\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
%    subtitle style={%
%    colback=#2!7,%
%    colframe=#2!50,%
%    boxsep=1mm,
%    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}}}
%}

% boîte créant la boîte résumé
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+o+O{\couleurresume}+m}{% %<--- modified
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=false,
    IfValueTF={#1}{%
      before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#3}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    }{%
      before upper={\textcolor{#2!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    },
    colframe=#2!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=#2!63!black,%
    leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,
    toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,
    left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
%    titreresume,
    boxed title style={
        colframe=#2!50,%
        colback=#2!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt},
%    soustitre,
    subtitle style={%
    colback=#2!7,%
    colframe=#2!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{#2!63!black}}},
    title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\couleurresume{red}%
\begin{resume}[2017]{chapitre 1}
\tcbsubtitle{Définition}

\lipsum[1]
\end{resume}

\def\couleurresume{blue}%
\begin{resume}[2018]{chapitre 1}

\tcbsubtitle{Propriétés}
\lipsum[2]
\end{resume}

%\show\tcbcounter
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the comments here. Please have longer discussion in the chat.