# How to duplicate in 2 x A5 a tcolorbox written in A5 format on several page?

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, printing

I wrote a `Dupli` environment that allows me to print two identical A5 pages on an A4 page.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% environnement Dupli
\newlength{\ligne}%
\newsavebox{\maboite}%
\newlength\tindent%
\newlength\ttopskip%

\newenvironment{Dupli}[1]{%
\def\mtfois{#1}%
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}%
 \setlength{\tindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\ligne}{0.46\textwidth}%
\setbox\maboite\hbox\bgroup%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.46\textwidth}%
}{%
\end{minipage}\egroup%
%\noindent% 
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
\foreach \i in {1,...,\mtfois} {%
%\vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\hfill\usebox{\maboite}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill%
\usebox{\maboite}\hfill{\null}%
}% fin de la parbox
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
\par\noindent%
}% fin du foreach \i
%\vfill
\setlength{\parindent}{\tindent}%
\setlength{\topskip}{\ttopskip}%
}
% fin environnement Dupli
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I use it to create course summaries with [these tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470933/138900).

[image: screenshot]

I would like this box to be able **to extend over several pages with the breakable option.**

But, the `Dupli` environment does not allow interruptions.

Currently, when a summary takes several pages, I create each page individually. I would like to create only one summary, but keep the number of the summary page *(1/3   2/3  3/3 etc)* in the upper right corner.

Full code of the screenshot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,landscape]{article}  
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    
\usepackage{atveryend}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
% environnement Dupli
\newlength{\ligne}%
\newsavebox{\maboite}%
\newlength\tindent%
\newlength\ttopskip%

\newenvironment{Dupli}[1]{%
\def\mtfois{#1}%
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}%
 \setlength{\tindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\ligne}{0.46\textwidth}%
\setbox\maboite\hbox\bgroup%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.46\textwidth}%
}{%
\end{minipage}\egroup%
%\noindent% 
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
\foreach \i in {1,...,\mtfois} {%
%\vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\hfill\usebox{\maboite}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill%
\usebox{\maboite}\hfill{\null}%
}% fin de la parbox
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}%
\par\noindent%
}% fin du foreach \i
%\vfill
\setlength{\parindent}{\tindent}%
\setlength{\topskip}{\ttopskip}%
}
% fin environnement Dupli
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470933/138900
%  resume box
\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}
  }{%
    \ifnum\month<9%
    \sfrac{\the\numexpr\year-1}{\the\year}%
    \else
    \sfrac{\the\year}{\the\numexpr\year+1}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\couleurresume{red}%
% style du titre « résumé du cours »
\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
    boxed title style={
        colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
        colback=\couleurresume!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
}

% style des soustitres des résumés
\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
    subtitle style={%
    colback=\couleurresume!7,%
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{\couleurresume!63!black}}}}
}

% style du titre-boxed des encadrés
\tcbset{titrecadre/.style={%
    minipage boxed title*=-.5\linewidth,
    boxed title style={
        boxrule=.8pt,boxsep=0pt,toptitle=0pt,
        colframe=\couleurresume!55,colback=white},
    halign title=left}
}


\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+o+m}{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-\linewidth/5},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    breakable,
    lower separated=false,
    IfValueTF={#1}{%
      before upper={\textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    }{%
      before upper={\textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbcounter/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    },
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=\couleurresume!63!black,%
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    titreresume,soustitre,title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
% end of resume box
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\def\couleurresume{red}%
\begin{Dupli}{1}
\begin{resume}{breakable resume}
\tcbsubtitle{long text}
\lipsum[1]



\end{resume}
\end{Dupli}
\end{document}
```

1. Is it possible to make my `Dupli` environment breakable so that I don't need to create as many summary boxes as pages?
2. If not, is it possible to obtain the same result in another way?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: I think this solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355586/1952) could be applied to this problem. You need to know how vertically large are your pages and compose them in two columns.

Comment: @Ignasi Thank you for your interest in this issue. What is your idea on this subject?  How to make sure that each page has the same tcolorbox twice and that it can be extended over several pages?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Instead of my answer, take a look at [leaflet example](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=407) in tcolorbox documentation. The `leaflet` is composed using a `tcbraster` filled with stored `magazine` boxes. You can adapt it using every fragment twice on same page. As soon as possible I'll provide an example but you'll have to wait a little.

Comment: @Ignasi It's very interesting, I'm in no hurry and I'll wait patiently. :-)

Comment: A first version of a `tcolorbox` solution is done. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code shows a solution with `tcolorbox` tools. It uses `magazine` library to break and store the desired text inside a `boxarray`, and later on these parts are printed using a `tcbraster`. This solution is based in [`Leaflet example`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=407) from `tcolorbox` documentation.

What's missing?:

- I could not save the array size to use it for reference in title
- Margins have to be tuned
- OP didn't explain how are titles for broken parts

The code until now looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, landscape]{article}  
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    
\usepackage{atveryend}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470933/138900
%  resume box
\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}
  }{%
    \ifnum\month<9%
    \sfrac{\the\numexpr\year-1}{\the\year}%
    \else
    \sfrac{\the\year}{\the\numexpr\year+1}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\couleurresume{red}%
% style du titre « résumé du cours »
\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
    boxed title style={
        colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
        colback=\couleurresume!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
}

% style des soustitres des résumés
\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
    subtitle style={%
    colback=\couleurresume!7,%
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{\couleurresume!63!black}}}}
}

% style du titre-boxed des encadrés
\tcbset{titrecadre/.style={%
    minipage boxed title*=-.5\linewidth,
    boxed title style={
        boxrule=.8pt,boxsep=0pt,toptitle=0pt,
        colframe=\couleurresume!55,colback=white},
    halign title=left}
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+o+m}{%
    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-3cm},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    breakable,
    width=.5\textwidth,
    break at=\textheight,
    reset box array,
    store to box array,
    lower separated=false,
    IfValueTF={#1}{%
      before upper={\textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbbreakpart/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    }{%
      before upper={\textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbbreakpart/\ref{nombre-de-resume}}},
    },
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=\couleurresume!63!black,%
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    titreresume,soustitre,title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
% end of resume box
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\def\couleurresume{red}%

%This "resume" is broken in parts and stores in "default" array.
\begin{resume}{breakable resume}
\tcbsubtitle{long text}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{resume}

%The array is printed inside a `tcbraster`
\boxarraygetsize{\mysize}
\begin{tcbraster}[blankest, raster columns=2]
\foreach \i in {1,...,\mysize}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \useboxarray{\i}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \useboxarray{\i}
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Following code shows some *improvements* (I hope so!) to previous solution:

1. Margins for printing (see comment). External margins are defined in `geometry` package options with `hmargin` and `vmargin`. Apart from these, every box is defined to have certain `width`. This width means the whole width for printed tcolorbox, including text and borders. If we want to print two equal boxes in parallel, maximum width for boxes will be `width=.5\textwidth`. Everything lower than this will allow to have some horizontal space between boxes.
2. Fragment enumeration. Command `\boxarraygetsize` saves number of fragments into a macro. This macro is stored in `.aux` file and referenced to compose fragment-num/total-fragments label in every box.
3. Fragment title. There's no fragment title but some space has been reserved with `pad after break` and label fragment-num/total-fragments is included with an `overlay` command.
4. Overall composition. In following code, `tcbraster` has been eliminated. I didn't know how to center stored boxes into raster columns (I think it's not possible) and the raster has been replaced by  `\useboxarray{\i}\hspace{...}\consumeboxarray{\i}\\`. This way two boxes are placed on every page because original text has been fragmented on `\textheight`. If `width` is less than `.5\textwidth` some `\hspace` can be included between boxes on same line.

Now the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, landscape]{article}  
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,2cm}, vmargin={2cm,2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}    
\usepackage{atveryend}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470933/138900
%  resume box
\NewDocumentCommand{\currentschoolyear}{+o}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \sfrac{#1}{\the\numexpr#1+1}
  }{%
    \ifnum\month<9%
    \sfrac{\the\numexpr\year-1}{\the\year}%
    \else
    \sfrac{\the\year}{\the\numexpr\year+1}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\def\couleurresume{red}%
% style du titre « résumé du cours »
\tcbset{titreresume/.style={
    boxed title style={
        colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
        colback=\couleurresume!10,%
        coltext=blue,%
    leftrule=1.5mm,rightrule=1.5mm,toprule=1.5pt,bottom=0pt,boxsep=1pt}}
}

% style des soustitres des résumés
\tcbset{soustitre/.style={
    subtitle style={%
    colback=\couleurresume!7,%
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    boxsep=1mm,
    fontupper={\sffamily\bfseries\large\selectfont\color{\couleurresume!63!black}}}}
}

% style du titre-boxed des encadrés
\tcbset{titrecadre/.style={%
    minipage boxed title*=-.5\linewidth,
    boxed title style={
        boxrule=.8pt,boxsep=0pt,toptitle=0pt,
        colframe=\couleurresume!55,colback=white},
    halign title=left}
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{resume}{+o+m}{%
%    minipage boxed title*=-106mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-3cm},
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    breakable,
    pad after break = 1cm,
    overlay middle and last={
        \node[anchor=north east, color=\couleurresume!63!black] at (interior.north east) {\thetcbbreakpart/\ref{nombre-de-array}};
    },
    width=.5\textwidth,
    break at=\textheight,
    reset box array,
    store to box array,
    lower separated=false,
    IfValueTF={#1}{%
      before upper={\textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\currentschoolyear[#1] \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbbreakpart/\ref{nombre-de-array}}},
    }{%
      before upper={\textcolor{\couleurresume!63!black}{\currentschoolyear \hfill{#2}\hfill\thetcbbreakpart/\ref{nombre-de-array}}},
    },
    colframe=\couleurresume!50,%
    colback=white,%
    coltitle=\couleurresume!63!black,%
leftrule=3mm,rightrule=3mm,toprule=2pt,bottomrule=2pt,left=3pt,right=0pt,top=3mm,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    titreresume,soustitre,title={\normalsize Résumé}
}

\makeatletter
\AfterLastShipout{%
%  \immediate\write\@auxout
%  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-resume}{{\thetcb@cnt@resume}{}}}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\newlabel{nombre-de-array}{{\mysize}{}}}%
}
\makeatother
% end of resume box
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\def\couleurresume{red}%

%This "resume" is broken in parts and stores them in "default" array.
\begin{resume}{breakable resume}
\tcbsubtitle{long text}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{resume}

\boxarraygetsize{\mysize}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\mysize}{%
        \centering
        \noindent\useboxarray{\i}\hspace*{0mm}%
        \consumeboxarray{\i}\\
}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting contribution. Since I don't have the time to analyze and implement it right now, I will deal with it as soon as possible.

Comment: This is a great improvement and a very good basis for work. Is it possible to leave a so-called printer margin around each of the A5 boxes?

Comment: @AndréC I've updated the answer. Hope it solves some of your questions.

Comment: It's almost perfect (to simplify the question, I had simplified the content of the box title).  As I understand it, this summary stores its content and it is written last. Why don't you use minipages to do this, which allows you to center both boxes?

Answer (score 5):

This exploits that `atbegshi`, which is loaded by `eso-pic`, puts the contents of the page in a box, `\AtBeginShipoutBox`. This box can be copied. The following is a proof of principle and works regardless of `tcolorbox`. It does, however, assume that the user is careful enough to confine the stuff on the left side of the page. There are many ways in which one can extend this (and I am sure that someone will do that because there is no way this answer will get accepted), and I openly admit that, because of the reason, I engineered some small shifts by hand rather than finding out precisely how one may compute them from the page geometry. Also, one does not need necessarily to use Ti*k*Z here, the mechanisms of `eso-pic` suffice, but you are loading `tcolorbox` so this is not much extra. At any rate, this example shows the principle: add a hook that copies the ship out box to the right half of the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at ([xshift=\textwidth/4+2em,yshift=0.9em]current page.center) {\copy\AtBeginShipoutBox};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {Duck,Marmot,Koala,Bear,Cat}
{\section{\X}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,width=0.46\textwidth]
  \lipsum[\Y]
\end{tcolorbox}}
\end{document}
```

(I should mention that there is software that does the same to a pdf file. At least that's what I believe, in the old days that was some postscript command, maybe `psnup`, maybe not, which allowed one to do that for ps files.)

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: There seems to be a misunderstanding: this solution does *not* produce as many boxes as pages. To make this even clearer, I add another example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at ([xshift=\textwidth/4+2em,yshift=0.9em]current page.center) {\copy\AtBeginShipoutBox};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{One very long box}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,width=0.46\textwidth]
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What could this be used for? Just duplication of the left column seems a bit boring to me. The point here is that you can play with Ti*k*Z. Here is an application that mirrors the left column, but obviously you could rotate it, change the opacity or even overt it (using `fadings`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at ([xshift=\textwidth/4+2em,yshift=0.9em]current page.center) 
[xscale=-1]{\copy\AtBeginShipoutBox};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{One very long box}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,width=0.46\textwidth]
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question. Your solution creates as many boxes as pages, I want a single box that extends over several pages. Nevertheless, this opens up interesting opportunities with other packages. I am therefore changing the title of the question.

Comment: @AndréC My solution does not produce as many (tcolor) boxes as pages. This is already evident from the first example I posted but to make it even more obvious I added a second example.

Comment: At the moment your solution works with your tcolorbox, not with the tcolorbox summary box I created.

Comment: @AndréC Unfortunately your post does not have a simple, ready-to-use tcolorbox that runs over several pages. If it had, I bet the solution would work. Please note that the answers are never just for the one who is asking it, but for everyone, so I do not see much of a point in trying to fix your code.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add the `breakable` option, but I still have some problems. In particular the centering is not correct.  And I use a decoration that appeals to the students *(frogbox from page 74 of the tcolorbox manual)* it is also placed on the cut boxes (whereas it should only appear once).

Comment: @AndréC Well, there is comment after comment making unsubstantiated statements. First you said the solution would just "create as many boxes as page", which was never the case. Then you said it wouldn't work, but you just forgot to put `breakable`. Now this statement on an issue, which is impossible for me to reproduce because it is not at all clear what you are talking about. The idea of this site is to make statements that are backed up by codes, i.e. minimal examples, and substantiated facts. I stop here, you will anyway not accept this answer, which may still be of interest for others.